# Argument of type '"game"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: any) => IGame'

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular8, ngrx, ngrx-store

My `IGame` interface and initial state is as follows:

```
export interface IGame {
  currentScore: number;
  highScore: number;
  keepPlaying: boolean;
  won: boolean;
  gameOver: boolean;
  winningValue: number;
  tiles: ITile[];
}

let initialState: IGame = {
  currentScore: 0,
  highScore: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("highScore")) || 0,
  keepPlaying: false,
  won: false,
  gameOver: false,
  winningValue: 2048,
  tiles: []
};
```

using it as follows:

```
export class GameService {
  public currentScore: Observable<number>;
  public highScore: Observable<number>;
  public tiles: Observable<ITile[] >;
  public gameOver: Observable<boolean>;
  public won: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private gridService: GridService, private store: Store<any>) {
    const store$ = store.select<IGame>('game');
    this.tiles = store$.pipe(map(({ tiles }: IGame) => tiles));
    this.currentScore = store$.pipe(
      map(({ currentScore }: IGame) => currentScore)
    );
    this.highScore = store$.pipe(map(({ highScore }: IGame) => highScore));
    this.gameOver = store$.pipe(map(({ gameOver }: IGame) => gameOver));
    this.won = store$.pipe(map(({ won }: IGame) => won));
  }
```

it gives following errors:

> ERROR in app/game/2048/services/game.service.ts:20:40 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"game"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: any) => IGame'.

Not getting why but as I have seen here https://ngrx.io/api/store/select it says we can pass `pathOrMapFn: string | ((state: T, props?: Props) => any)`

Comment: it is just a guess, but I assume that the Storage will give you a asynchronous result, hence `store.select<IGame>('game')` won't work. The Typedef in the documentation is also, that I is an Observable. try   `store.select<Observable<IGame>>('game')`, because it looks like you already treat it like an Observable. Also be consitent with typedefs. In the constructor you shout use `private store : Store<AppState>`

Comment: How did you provide the reducers ?